# How do you pass an XML file from an external application into Orbeon Form Runner to populate a pre-made form?

Tags: orbeon

I am a new user to Orbeon. I am attempting to integrate Orbeon with another e-form type application that does not support mobile viewing. is it possible to pass an XML file to Form Runner to open and populate a pre-built form with the values from the xml file for editing? We would subsequently send the updated XML back to our other application and we already have this functionality built. if possible what is the best way to accomplish? I am still digesting all of the Orbeon knowledge and flow of the application, so be gentle =p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but it should be possible using the [Persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api).

You'll also need to [configure access to the API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/page-flow-controller/authorization). For testing purposes, I used the properties in the [Backward compatibility](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/page-flow-controller/authorization#TOC-Backward-compatibility) section to completely open up API access.

Comment: Thanks will try to play with this.

Comment: You're welcome. For sending the XML back to your other application, you may also want to look at [More powerful buttons](http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/04/more-powerful-buttons.html), specifically the `send` action.